# PHP template get data

Tags: php, templates, loops

Imagine this scenario:

- DB table tasks
- DB table tasks_work

I want to display tasks and time spent on each task (task_work).

Controller_Tasks gets data from Model_Tasks and passes to the view an multidimensional array containing tasks (id, title..) on which I do a `foreach` loop, and I want to get the corresponding task work for each task.

What I did in similar previous projects, is the template calling the controller inside the template's `foreach` loop, but i think it´s not a good practice.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
On the Controller_Tasks i did this:

```
foreach ($this->View->tasks as $task ): extract( $task );
    #multidimensional array with id of task
    $this->View->tasks_work[$task['id_crm_tasks']] = $Model_Tasks_Work->read('id_task = '.$task['id_crm_tasks'],'','','','time');
endforeach;
```

And on the template, when looping the tasks, I get the task work by:

```
    <? foreach($this->tasks_work[$task_id_crm_tasks] as $task_work ):?>

        <?=$task_work['time']?>

    <? endforeach?>
```

It´s working, and the template is calling nothing!

Comment: Because this has completely no information, that would actually let someone to debug it. Your post in it's current form expects users to guess, what could be causing the problem.

Comment: It´s not really a problem, i was searching for the best practice to get data on the view (template, as you call it) on an MVC structure.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your architecture, this kind of tasks can easily handled by native sql query. More friendly solution is to add method to your model capable of getting this information. Another solution would be making dedicated service. Looping on model data in view to get one number is really bad practice. What are you using for framework?

Comment: Native sql query how? Using some join? How to loop the info on the view, because i will have many task_work for one task.
I´m using my one MVC framework.

Comment: [Here](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/joining-with-group-by-and-order-by.php) is example how to do it. No need to loop, group by is your friend.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you wanted sum and individual hours as well.